# Waiting for coroutine result without blocking main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, callback, kotlin-coroutines

I've to update an item in a fragment based on the data returned from the network call. I don't want to block the main thread and end up with ANR so I adopted the approach of "callbacks" however I wonder if there's a way to wait for the result from the network call without relying on the callback mechanism using coroutines

**Current implementation**

*MyFragment.kt*

```
fun updateButtonText() {
   handlerClass.getData {
      //received data from the server update the button text
   }
}
```

*HandlerClass.kt*

```
fun getData(callback: (String) -> Unit) {
   scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val data = mySuspendedNetworkcallMethod()

      callback.invoke(data)
   }
}
```

**Desired Implementation:**

*MyFragment.kt*

```
fun updateButtonText() {
   val data = handlerClass.getData()
   button.text = data
}
```

*HandlerClass.kt*

```
suspend fun getData() {
   return mySuspendedNetworkcallMethod()
}
```

For the desired demo implementation, I understand, I'd have to use runBlocking{} to call a suspended method however runBlocking{} will block the calling thread - which in this case would be the Main Thread until `getData()` returns the data.

*I don't want to block the main thread but still be able to cal & wait for the suspended method to fetch the data and then update the button.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines are designed to get rid of callbacks. You can use [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) in the `Fragment` class to launch a lifecycle-aware coroutine, it will look like the following:

*MyFragment.kt*:

```
fun updateButtonText() = lifecycleScope.launch {
   button.text = handlerClass.getData()
}
```

*HandlerClass.kt*:

```
suspend fun getData() {
   return mySuspendedNetworkcallMethod()
}
```

If you use `MVVM` approach you should consider to use `ViewModel` and it's [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) extension to launch coroutines.

For `LifecycleScope`, use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0` or higher.

For `ViewModelScope`, use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0` or higher.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that the Handler class is going to be like a library/interface to get this data from anywhere wether in fragment or in another utility class. In that I won't have the option to use lifecycleScope. Is there any other way around it?

Comment: Another question: since the lifeCycleScope is running on the main thread (updating the UI) wouldn't it block the main thread when the `getData()` is called?

Comment: Why you won't have the option to use `lifecycleScope`? Is it library for android apps? `getData()` function in the Handler class is a `suspend` function, it can be called from any coroutine, even from a coroutine launched with `lifecycleScope`.  It shouldn't block the main thread. However I don't know how `mySuspendedNetworkcallMethod` is implemented so I can't be sure 100%. You can test.

Answer (score 0):

Well recommended way is to use viewmodel and viewmodelscope for suspend functions.

However in your situation, just use lifecyclescope

```
    fun updateButtonText() {
       lifecycleScope.launch{
          val data = handlerClass.getData()
          button.text = data
       }
    }
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines